# Why can't I access the Assets folder of my Xamarin.Android project this way?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to set the Typeface of the TextView to a font in the Assets folder. The problem-code is "var font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Assets, "Enter-The-Grid.ttf");," not the first use, but the second one towards the end of my code (the red squiggly line appears under "Assets").

```
namespace UndergroundSports.Android
{
[Activity]
public class CityPage : Activity
{
    Sport[] sports = Sport.Sports;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.CityPage);

        var font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Assets, "Enter-The-Grid.ttf");

        Button bttJoin = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.bttJoin);
        bttJoin.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            gotoJoinPage();
        };

        bttJoin.Typeface = font;

        ListView lstSports = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lstSport);
        lstSports.Adapter = new SportsAdapter(this, sports);

        lstSports.ItemClick += (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e) =>
        {
            Sport selectedFromList = sports[e.Position];
            Global.Instance.CurrentSport = selectedFromList;
            gotoMembersPage();
        };
    }

    private void gotoJoinPage()
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(JoinPage));
        StartActivity(intent);
    }

    private void gotoMembersPage()
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MembersPage));
        StartActivity(intent);
    }

    public class SportsAdapter : BaseAdapter<Sport>
    {
        Sport[] items;
        Activity context;
        public SportsAdapter(Activity context, Sport[] items) : base()
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.items = items;
        }
        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }
        public override Sport this[int position]
        {
            get { return items[position]; }
        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get { return items.Length; }
        }
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null)
                view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(global::Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, null);
            TextView txtView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(global::Android.Resource.Id.Text1);
            var font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Assets, "Enter-The-Grid.ttf");
            txtView.Text = items[position].Name;
            txtView.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
            txtView.Typeface = font;
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

}

But when I tried to create a variable containing the font I got an error telling me:

Cannot access a nonstatic member of outer type `Android.Content.Context' via nested type`UndergroundSports.Android.CityPage.SportsAdapter' (CS0038) (UndergroundSportsAndroid)"

From looking at related questions I think I need to either create an instance of the Assets object or make it static.

I'm pretty new to C# and don't really understand what's going on. I would appreciate it if someone could explain why I'm unable to access Assets in this part of my code. The part that confuses me the most is that I use the exact same line of code to access the font earlier within the same file without getting that error.

Comment: SportsAdapter is a class nested inside of your CityPage Activity.  SportsAdapter doesn't know what Context is.  CityPage does.  The easiest way to fix this would be to pass Context in as a parameter or property when you create the instance of SportsAdapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(context.Assets, "Enter-The-Grid.ttf");
```

Pass your activity's instance to your adapter via constructor, and use it to access Assests

```
public class SportsAdapter : BaseAdapter<Sport>
{
    Sport[] items;
    Activity context;
    public SportsAdapter(Activity context, Sport[] items) : base()
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    ....

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null)
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(global::Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, null);
        TextView txtView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(global::Android.Resource.Id.Text1);
        var font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(context.Assets, "Enter-The-Grid.ttf");
        txtView.Text = items[position].Name;
        txtView.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
        txtView.Typeface = font;
        return view;
    }
}
```

Also, make sure your .ttf file's build action is set to AndroidAssests. Right the .tff file > Build Action > AndroidAsset

Comment: I compared the code in your answer to my current code and it's exactly the same. Did you mean to include the changes you recommended? That would be helpful if you did.

Comment: var font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(context.Assets, "Enter-The-Grid.ttf"); see this line. It's context.Assets